# Teradata string truncated after UNION ALL

Tags: teradata, union-all

I have a query with a UNION clause. One of the field is a plain hardcoded string. The string in the statement after UNION gets truncated to match the string length of the field before the UNION. 
Sounds confusing? Here's an example.

```
SELECT 'abc' as xxx 
FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
select 'defghi' as xxx
FROM tbl2;
```

For the above query, I would expect the output to be

```
abc
defghi
```

However, the output is

```
abc
def
```

Any thoughts?

**EDIT :**
The workaround, I am aware of currently is to have the SELECT statement with the longer string appear before the UNION. i.e

```
SELECT 'defghi' as xxx 
FROM tbl2
UNION ALL
select 'abc' as xxx
FROM tbl1;
```

This would give me the expected output. But is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first datatype is taken, but you can cast that to your desired datatype like to a char(6) in that case, else the column will remain char(3)

```
SELECT CAST('abc' as char(6)) as xxx 
FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
select 'defghi' as xxx
FROM tbl2;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the query doesn't execute. It throws a syntactical error.

Comment: The above query works if it's char(6) instead of nvarchar(6). Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please update your query, so I could accept your answer.

Comment: changed it to varchar forgot that nvarchar does not exist in teradata

Comment: `CAST('abc' AS varchar(255))` worked for me. TD 14.10.07.07

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to set a datatype of the first row.

```
SELECT 'abc' (varchar(99))  as xxx 
FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
select 'defghi' as xxx
FROM tbl2;
```