# MySQL query with UNION returns trimmed string

Tags: mysql, database, union

I have two tables with the same JSON column. My query needs to UNION some rows from both. The problem is that UNION trims the result (see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/506e43/1/1).
The solution here ([Teradata string truncated after UNION ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159890/teradata-string-truncated-after-union-all)) is to cast the column to CHAR(n) but in my case, this won't work because the length of the result may vary from 200 to 2000 characters (or sometimes more).

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure if it’s an issue with the UNION, but I had a very similar issue with an application that was crashing for larger partners - we found out MySQL group_concat hard trimmed the output. For us it was anything over 1024 characters was dropped - and since we were expecting XML - undesired output.

You can set the max length of group_concat to something much larger in your my.ini file, or if you need for temporary large things, we sometimes set it during the session similar to this: [MySQL and GROUP_CONCAT() maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567000/mysql-and-group-concat-maximum-length)

(From above post)

`SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
select group_concat(column) from table group by column`

Here’s info in their docs - and you can click into the property for more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it works. But for sure I'd like to understand why the query without UNION works but no the query without it.

Comment: hmm, more research it seems potentially this may be an issue? when using union all and group_concat, if you don't set the length, people are getting truncated results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733920/mysql-group-concatutf8-in-union-truncated-to-1024-3?rq=1